# if array element is empty remove double <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Array which is like:

```
var Arr = [
    { forname: 'John', surname: 'Doe', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com', website: 'www.johndoe.com', phone: '0123456789', img: 'img/johndoe.jpg' },
    { forname: 'Jane', surname: 'Doe', email: '', website: 'www.janedoe.com', phone: '0123456789', img: 'img/janedoe.jpg' },
          ]
```

what I do is filling a div with `id="#caption"`

```
$('#caption').html(e[f].forname + ' ' + e[f].surname + '<br>' + e[f].email + '<br>' + e[f].website + '<br>' + e[f].phone);
```

`e` and `f` are parameter passed through a function and they select each array object. The problem I have now is, when I get the data of both in the caption div it looks like:

[image: THIS]

because `Jane Doe` has no E-Mail adress. I don't know who and which fields are having a value or not. What I want to do is, that fields with no value get the double `<br>` removed.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to remove, try not to put them in the first place

Comment: @Ibu but I need them to make a line break. I don't know when I'm needing a break or not. Do you get it?

Comment: Generally, if each field is put into a `<div>`, then they will each get their own line. It's easy to start abusing divs, but they're undeniably pretty useful.

Comment: @Katana314 so simple yet so good! Will you make it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of using `<br>` blocks (denote where the line breaks are) use `<div>`s (denote where the lines are). Like `<p>`aragraphs, they use a line each because of the default `display: block` property, but have fewer default-formatting properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some trickery

```
[
  e[f].forname+" "+e[f].surname,
  e[f].email,
  e[f].website,
  e[f].phone
].filter(function(n){ return n != undefined && n != ''; }).join('<br/>');
```

Any empty values will be skipped and no double 
 will be added

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
+ e[f].email + '<br>' +
```

try

```
+ (e[f].email ? e[f].email + '<br>' : '') +
```

This will insert `email + '<br>'` only if there is an email.

Do this for all fields.

EDIT

```
$('#caption').html(
  e[f].forname + ' ' + (e[f].surname ? e[f].surname + '<br>' : '') +
  (e[f].email ? e[f].email + '<br>' : '') +
  (e[f].website ? e[f].website + '<br>' : '')
  (e[f].phone ? e[f].phone + '<br>' : ''
);
```

Comment: sorry this does not seem to work. Now I only get the first element displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an empty string:

```
$('#caption').html(e[f].forname + ' ' + e[f].surname + '<br>' + e[f].email + (( e[f].email=="")?"":'<br>') + e[f].website + '<br>' + e[f].phone);
```

(and if it's null you can check four null)

just check if it's empty and if it's empty -> don't put `<br>`

Just use the [tenary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).